# How to add spacing between input text fields side by side?

Tags: html, css, input, spacing

How to add spacing between input text fields side by side?

Required spaces in the marked area:

[image]

```html
<label for="Std">Start Trade Date</label>
<input type="text" id="Std" name="Std" placeholder="Enter start date">


<label for="End">End trade Date</label>
<input type="text" id="End" name="End" placeholder="Enter end date">

<label for="Fqy">Frequency</label>
<input type="text" id="Fqy" name="Fqy" placeholder="Frequency">
```

Comment: the question body is weird... but to answer the title you might just have a style with `margin-right: 1em;` (for example) and `display: inline-block;` to have them next to each other

Comment: @DiegoD, inputs are by default `inline`-elements. They will be displayed next to each other by default. If they aligned next to each other by using flexbox or grid then you should use the gap property

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like `display: flex` with a [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) value.

I added `wrap` because it can help with when the screen size/parent element is too small. You can also see how the gap is maintained between rows and columns...

```css
.dispalyFlex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="dispalyFlex">
  <div>
    <label for="Std">Start Trade Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="Std" name="Std" placeholder="Enter start date">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="End">End trade Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="End" name="End" placeholder="Enter end date">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="Fqy">Frequency</label>
    <input type="text" id="Fqy" name="Fqy" placeholder="Frequency">
  </div>
</div>
```